# what is the Dirty state of a DataGridView Button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

a DataGridViewCheckBox has a dirty state, user checks the checkbox but It does not change the value property.

But when it comes to DataGridViewButton, what is it's dirty state?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one.  A button column is not for displaying or editing values; it is for enabling the user to perform an action for a row.  Think about a regular Button.  Can you change its value?  Of course not.  Unlike for TextBoxes, CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc, Buttons don;t have a logical value so their value cannot be changed.